# Loop Python Script

Tags: python, loops

Im new to python and I am currently working on a python script and want to add a loop at the end of it, currently the code is as follows:

```
#FinalGrade

print ("\n")
Institution = str(input("Please Enter the Name of Your insitution: "))
print ("\n")
Year = str(input("Please Enter the Year of the Student (For Example, 'Year 2'): "))
print ("\n")
Student = str(input("Student Full Name: "))
print ("\n")
Grade1 = int(input("Enter Student's First Term Grade: "))
Grade2 = int(input("Enter Student's Second Term Grade: "))
Grade3 = int(input("Enter Student's Third Term Grade: "))
Grade4 = int(input("Enter Student's Fourth Term Grade: "))

average =  (Grade1+Grade2+Grade3+Grade4)/4

print ("\n")
print ("Total Grade Average: %G" % (average))

passed_or_failed = "PASSED"
if average < 40:
   passed_or_failed = 'FAILED'

print ("\n")
print ("%s has: %s" % (Student, passed_or_failed))
```

Id like to find out if it would be possible to set a loop so another student can be entered, would this be possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Why not put it in an infinite loop?

```
cont = 'y'
while cont=='y':
    print ("\n")
    Institution = str(input("Please Enter the Name of Your insitution: "))
    print ("\n")
    Year = str(input("Please Enter the Year of the Student (For Example, 'Year 2'): "))
    print ("\n")
    Student = str(input("Student Full Name: "))
    print ("\n")
    Grade1 = int(input("Enter Student's First Term Grade: "))
    Grade2 = int(input("Enter Student's Second Term Grade: "))
    Grade3 = int(input("Enter Student's Third Term Grade: "))
    Grade4 = int(input("Enter Student's Fourth Term Grade: "))

    average =  (Grade1+Grade2+Grade3+Grade4)/4

    ...
    cont = input('Do you want to keep entering students? y/n: ')
```

Or if you want to keep all of the results:

```
results = []
cont = 'y'

while cont=='y':
    print ("\n")
    Institution = str(input("Please Enter the Name of Your insitution: "))
    ...

    passed_or_failed = "PASSED"
    if average < 40:
       passed_or_failed = 'FAILED'
    results.append(passed_or_failed)
    ...
    cont = input('Do you want to keep entering students? y/n: ')
```

And you can just loop through the results to see them.

Comment: Might want to add a `quit` option :)

Comment: Thank you! The loop works correctly however if I enter 'n' it still decides to loop again, any solution for this? @alKid

Comment: To you redefine `cont` anywhere?  Put `print(repr(cont))` beneath the `while` statement to see its value each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You mean just one more student to be entered?

You can probably do that with a while or for loop. Something along these lines:

```
counter = 0
while (counter < 2):
    your existing code
    ....
    counter += 1
```